# UITableView endUpdates taking very long time when CoreData updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a Core Data app that displays a large amount of instances in an `UITableView`.

We have a `mainQueueContext` running in the main thread and a `privateQueueContext` running in a background thread.

We load the data in the UITableView without problems, but when we load a refreshed version from the API we save it to the `privateQueueContext` and merge it in the `mainQueueContext`

```
[self.mainQueueContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
```

It takes a few seconds to trigger the call to

```
-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

Which trigger the call to:

```
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Then the App hangs and CPU goes to 100% and memory begins to rise indefinitely until it runs out of memory. (see picture below)

[image: CPU during the processing]

[image: Memory consumption during endUpdates]

With less than 1000 elements this problem does not happen. I was wondering if any of you saw something like this.

### Edit

Here's some data from instruments
[image: Instruments data showing endUpdates]

Comment: Show some code?  Use Instruments to see where your app is entering an infinite loop?

Comment: @Paulw11I added instruments data.

Comment: Are you not using `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` or `estimatedRowHeight`?

Comment: @bteapot no, but I changed it and it didn't help

Comment: Then reload your table's data on `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` instead of merging changes. See here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/211/, from 25:30.

Comment: i also faced this problem, i think may missed else condition somewhere .

Answer (score 1):

One improvement you can do is to use [fetchBatchSize](http://apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/fetchBatchSize).

From Apple Doc"

> When the fetch is executed, the entire request is evaluated and the
>   identities of all matching objects recorded, but no more than
>   batchSize objects’ data will be fetched from the persistent store at a
>   time. The array returned from executing the request will be a proxy
>   object that transparently faults batches on demand. (In database
>   terms, this is an in-memory cursor.)

You could also use fetchLimit and fetchOffset to implement pagination.

Cheers,
Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this problem too. I ended up gathering all updated into array on `controller: didChangeObject:` recording index path, NSFetchedResultsChangeType, and object itself. On `controllerDidChangeContent:` I was looking if its count is larger than X, if it is then just reload whole table (it's much more efficient) and if it's not then apply all changes normally as if it was happening in `didChangeObject:` method. It just doesn't make sense to insert/delete/move so much cells, as user won't see most of these changes anyway.

I hope this approach will help you!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. In my case the solution was to remove setting explicitly `rowHeight` of the tableView to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I used instead the delegate `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`
Although the documentation of rowHeight seems to state the opposite:

> There are performance implications to using tableView(*:heightForRowAt:) instead of rowHeight. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView(*:heightForRowAt:) on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

Comment: Thanks~ I have 500+ row and after using your solution, my APP is faster 0.8 second than before. But this only work when every single row height is the same situation.